# How to check if json array already contains a certain key?

Tags: sql, json, postgresql, jsonb

Let's say I have this json in my jsonb column

```
{
  "fields": [
    {
      "name": "firstName",
    },
    {
      "name": "lastName",
    },
    ...
}
```

How can I know if the "firstName" already exist?

I've tried this so far

```
SELECT field->>'fields' 
from person where (field->'name')::jsonb ? 'firstName';
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the [containment operator `@>`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html):

```
select field->>'fields'
from person
where field->'fields' @> '[{"name": "firstName"}]'
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use `json_array_elements` to generate fields elements so you can filter based on `'name'`.

```
SELECT field->>'fields', obj.*
from person, jsonb_array_elements_text(field->'fields') obj
where obj = '{"name": "firstName"}'
```

see [dbfiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/#&togetherjs=J1RiUQeFBE)

Comment: I got this error ```Query 1 ERROR: ERROR:  function json_array_elements(jsonb) does not exist
LINE 2: from person, json_array_elements(field->'fields') obj
                     ^
HINT:  No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
```

Comment: but before doing that i did some cleanup on your json samlple

Comment: btw, my column type is ```jsonb```

Comment: anyways, you can use jsonb_array_elements_text